# Drawing borders around a group of components in Matlab Appdesigner

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer, matlab-gui

I am using Matlab 2019b Appdesigner.

I have an app with many buttons, user input boxes etc and for making the navigation easier, I want to draw borders around a group of components which are under the same functionality. How can I do this?

Edit: Thanks to Rotem, I see that I can use the Panel Container for this. But is there a way to change the color or width of the border. I see only option to do it if it was created with GUIDE, but not Appdesigner.

Comment: Use the **Panel** container for grouping the components.

Comment: You should add your code or part of it to help us understand your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rotem. Does exactly what I wanted. Dont know how i missed it!